# What cosmetic was removed in MoreCompany 1.5.0?

Tags: mods, lethal-company

The Lethal Company mod [MoreCompany](https://thunderstore.io/c/lethal-company/p/notnotnotswipez/MoreCompany/) includes several wearable cosmetics. However, the patch notes for version 1.5.0 say:

> - Removed 1 cosmetic.

What cosmetic item was removed in 1.5.0?